# weblogic update from 11g to 12c

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

Currently I trying to update the project to weblogic 12c. After I using jdk8 to build it and try to deploy it to weblogic 12c, it throws below exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class not found for link: DataSourceStatusEnquiryWebS:    available:{AppointmentSlotSearchingWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.AppointmentSlotSearchEJBBean, CheckIssuedGopdHandheldFolderWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.CheckIssuedGopdHandheldFolderEJBBean, ReferralFeedbackEnquiryWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.ReferralFeedbackEnquiryEJBBean, PasmShrRelatedServiceWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.PasmShrRelatedServiceEJBBean, AppointmentCancelWebS_1=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.appointmentcancel.v1.AppointmentCancelEJBBean, OpasServiceEnquiryWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.OpasServiceEnquiryEJBBean, OpasServiceEnquiryWebS_3=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.opasserviceenquiry.v3.OpasServiceEnquiryEJBBean, PasCmsSecurityWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.PasCmsSecurityEJBBean, OpasConDisSummaryWebS_1=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.opascondissummary.v1.OpasConDisSummaryEJBBean, AppointmentEnquiryWebS_4=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.appointmentenquiry.v4.AppointmentEnquiryEJBBean, PasNtssRelatedServiceWebS_1=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.pasntssrelatedservice.v1.PasNtssRelatedServiceEJBBean, DmsGetOpasInfoWebS_1=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.dmsgetopasinfo.v1.DmsGetOpasInfoEJBBean, MarkAppointmentAssessmentConsultationStatusWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.MarkAppointmentAssessmentConsultationStatusEJBBean, PdisRelatedServiceWebS_1=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.pdisrelatedservice.v1.PdisRelatedServiceEJBBean, AppointmentEnquiryWebS_3=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.appointmentenquiry.v3.AppointmentEnquiryEJBBean, PspPatientListWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.PspPatientListEJBBean, CheckIssuedGopdA4FolderWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.CheckIssuedGopdA4FolderEJBBean, PasAdsRelatedServiceWebS_1=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.adswebservice.v1.PasAdsRelatedServiceEJBBean, OpasMoeServiceWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.OpasMoeServiceEJBBean, WorkStationServiceWebS_1=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.workstationservice.v1.WorkStationServiceEJBBean, PasCcaRelatedServiceWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.PasCcaRelatedServiceWebSEJBBean, FcsSopdAttendanceWebS_1=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.fcssopdattendance.v1.FcsSopdAttendanceEJBBean, AppointmentEnquiryWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.AppointmentEnquiryEJBBean, CheckPatientUnderCareWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.CheckPatientUnderCareEJBBean, BookedEdcUpdateWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.BookedEdcUpdateEJBBean, IssueGopdHandheldFolderWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.IssueGopdHandheldFolderEJBBean, BookedEdcEnquiryWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.BookedEdcEnquiryEJBBean, AppointmentBookingWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.AppointmentBookingEJBBean, FcsGetOpasInfoWebS_1=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.fcsgetopasinfo.v1.FcsGetOpasInfoEJBBean, OpasLetterServiceWebS_3=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.opasletterservice.v3.OpasLetterServiceEJBBean, UpdateUnconfirmAttendanceWebS=class hk.org.ha.pas.webservice.UpdateUnconfirmAttendanceEJBBean}
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.WSEEAnnotationProcessor.loadPorts(WSEEAnnotationProcessor.java:371)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.WSEEAnnotationProcessor.load(WSEEAnnotationProcessor.java:337)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.WSEEAnnotationProcessor.process(WSEEAnnotationProcessor.java:75)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.jaxws.JAXWSAnnotationProcessor.process(JAXWSAnnotationProcessor.java:73)
    ... 134 more

Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Unable to invoke Annotation processoror
    at weblogic.j2ee.wsee.compiler.WSEEModuleHelper.processAnnotations(WSEEModuleHelper.java:287)
    at weblogic.j2ee.wsee.compiler.WSEEModuleHelper.processAnnotationsWithServiceLinks(WSEEModuleHelper.java:245)
    at weblogic.j2ee.wsee.compiler.WSEEModuleHelper.processAnnotations(WSEEModuleHelper.java:187)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.WSEEEJBToolsModuleExtension.processAnnotations(WSEEEJBToolsModuleExtension.java:121)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.WSEEEJBToolsModuleExtension.merge(WSEEEJBToolsModuleExtension.java:87)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.MergeModuleFlow.compile(MergeModuleFlow.java:44)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.BaseMerger.merge(BaseMerger.java:20)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.mergeInput(AppMergerFlow.java:75)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.compile(AppMergerFlow.java:40)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
    ... 115 more
```

and one of the webservice class is annotate with:

```
@Stateless(name = "DataSourceStatusEnquiryWebS",
           mappedName = "pas_service-DataSourceEnquiryEJBBean")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
@WebService(serviceName = "DataSourceStatusEnquiryWebS")
@Policy(uri = "policy:UsernameToken.xml")
public class DataSourceStatusEnquiryEJBBean
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is missing definition in ejb-jar.xml. After I defined the ejb, I can deploy successfully.